# How to start TimescaleDB compression job?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I has load huge amounts of historical data into timescaledb table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE quotes (
    "time" timestamp NULL,
    symbol_id int4 NULL,
    "open" numeric(14,6) NULL,
    "close" numeric(14,6) NULL,
    high numeric(14,6) NULL,
    low numeric(14,6) NULL,
    volume int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT quotes_ts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (symbol_id, "time")
);

SELECT create_hypertable('quotes', 'time', 'symbol_id', 1, create_default_indexes => false);

ALTER TABLE quotes SET (
  timescaledb.compress,
  timescaledb.compress_segmentby = 'symbol_id'
);

SELECT add_compress_chunks_policy('quotes', INTERVAL '7 days');
```

After that I has inserted data into the table:

```sql
insert into quotes ("time", data_id, "open", "close", high, low, volume)
select "time", symbol_id, "open", "close", high, low, volume
from source_schema.quotes;
```

And I see what data are not compressed.

```sql
SELECT * FROM timescaledb_information.compressed_chunk_stats 
ORDER BY compression_status, hypertable_name, chunk_name;
```

Also I can select chunks with old data what must was compressed (it was my expectation).

```sql
SELECT show_chunks('quotes', older_than => INTERVAL '7 days');
```

If I try to compress chunk, it works well:

```sql
SELECT compress_chunk('_timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_59_chunk');
```

But how I can start internal timescaledb job for automatic compression of chunks according to specified policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "SELECT add_compress_chunks_policy('quotes', INTERVAL '7 days');" should start that automated process for any chunks older than 7 days old. (That is, the *end* of the chunk must be >= 7 days old.)

You can also see an informational view of your compressed data, or of the background worker tasks:

https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#timescaledb_information-compressed_hypertable_stats
https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#timescaledb_information-compressed_chunk_stats
https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#timescaledb_information-policy_stats

Not sure exactly from information you provide why you aren't seeing compressed data.  Might be easier to help debug on our community slack channel at slack.timescale.com.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, it helps: `SELECT * FROM timescaledb_information.policy_stats; SELECT alter_job_schedule(1000, next_start => '2020-07-03 17:34:00.0+00');`

Comment: Finding the job_id changed with TSDB v2. It is now SELECT * FROM timescaledb_information.job_stats;
https://docs.timescale.com/latest/release-notes/changes-in-timescaledb-2#cagg-information-views

Comment: device_id , count , time
If i add a compression policy of older than 7 days, does it mean i can still do insert,delete,update before that 7 days?